# How do I compare two JSON Objects to get new JSON for changes like add,delete,change using c#

Tags: c#, json

Can anyone help in getting the output Json by comparing two JSON which has same hierarchy, by showing JStatus as Change, Added, Delete. we have JStatus present in each Json, after comparison it will fill with status "change"/"add"/"delete", the values should be from new (2nd json) for changed objects, and value of old (in case of delete) json1.

please help

1st Base JSON (output should treat this as base JSON)

```
[{"Decision":{"id":"1","identifier":"Base1","dec_id":10,"JStatus":"","objects":[{"id":"1","identifier":"Base2","JStatus":""},{"id":"2","identifier":"Base3","JStatus":""}]}}]
```

2nd JSON

```
[{"Decision":{"id":"2","identifier":"Base1","dec_id":12,"JStatus":"","objects":[{"id":"1","identifier":"Base2","JStatus":"","textitem":[{"id":"1","identifier":"Base3","JStatus":"","objNewActivity":[{"id":"1","identifier":"Base4","JStatus":""}],"objNewGebiedsaanwijzingen":[{"id":"1","identifier":"Base5","JStatus":""}],"objNewBegrippen":[{"id":"1","identifier":"Base6","JStatus":""}],"objNewLocation":null}]}]}}]
```

OutPut required JSON

```
[{"Decision":{"id":"2","identifier":"Base1","dec_id":12,"JStatus":"Change","objects":[{"id":"1","identifier":"Base2","JStatus":"","textitem":[{"id":"1","identifier":"Base3","JStatus":"Add","objNewActivity":[{"id":"1","identifier":"Base4","JStatus":"Add"}],"objNewGebiedsaanwijzingen":[{"id":"1","identifier":"Base5","JStatus":"Add"}],"objNewBegrippen":[{"id":"1","identifier":"Base6","JStatus":"Add"}],"objNewLocation":null}]},{"id":"2","identifier":"Base3","JStatus":"Delete"}]}}]
```

I tried https://www.nuget.org/packages/JsonDiffer following but that only show me changes,

```
var j1 = JToken.Parse(readJson("Json1.txt"));
        var j2 = JToken.Parse(readJson("Json2.txt"));

        var diff = JsonDifferentiator.Differentiate(j1, j2, OutputMode.Detailed, showOriginalValues: true);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is PSEUDO CODE
Because I do not know the specific logic you wish to employ to make your comparisons and/or overwrites.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace StackDemo5
{
    public class StackDemo5Main
    {
        string json1 = "{ \"LoginSettings\": { \"Type\": \"Test\", \"Login\": \"Bitcoin\", \"Password\": \"123456\", \"SHA1Login\": \"Some hash\", \"SHA1Password\": \"Some hash\" }, \"Info1\": {\"Is_Active\": false, \"Amount\": 12 }, \"Info2\": { \"Is_Active\": true, \"Amount\": 41 }}";
        string json2 = "{ \"LoginSettings\": { \"Type\": \"\", \"Login\": \"\", \"Password\": \"\", \"SHA1Login\": \"\", \"SHA1Password\": \"\"  }, \"Info1\": { \"Is_Active\": false, \"Amount\": 0  }, \"Info2\": { \"Is_Active\": false, \"Amount\": 0  }, \"Info3\": { \"Is_Active\": false, \"Amount\": 0 },  \"Info4\": { \"Is_Active\": false, \"Amount\": 0 }}";


        public string CreateJsonAggregate() {
            Root first = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json1);
            Root second = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json2);

            Root third = new Root();
            third.LoginSettings = first.LoginSettings;
            third.Info1 = first.Info1;
            third.Info2 = first.Info2;
            third.Info3 = second.Info3;
            third.Info4 = second.Info4;

            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(third);
        }

        public class LoginSettings
        {
            public string Type { get; set; }
            public string Login { get; set; }
            public string Password { get; set; }
            public string SHA1Login { get; set; }
            public string SHA1Password { get; set; }
        }

        public class Info1
        {
            public bool Is_Active { get; set; }
            public int Amount { get; set; }
        }

        public class Info2
        {
            public bool Is_Active { get; set; }
            public int Amount { get; set; }
        }

        public class Info3
        {
            public bool Is_Active { get; set; }
            public int Amount { get; set; }
        }

        public class Info4
        {
            public bool Is_Active { get; set; }
            public int Amount { get; set; }
        }

        public class Root
        {
            public LoginSettings LoginSettings { get; set; }
            public Info1 Info1 { get; set; }
            public Info2 Info2 { get; set; }
            public Info3 Info3 { get; set; }
            public Info4 Info4 { get; set; }
        }
    }

    public class StackDemo6 {
        public string CreateJsonAggregate()
        {
            string input1 = "[{\"Decision\":{\"id\":\"1\",\"identifier\":\"Base1\",\"dec_id\":10,\"JStatus\":\"\",\"objects\":[{\"id\":\"1\",\"identifier\":\"Base2\",\"JStatus\":\"\"},{\"id\":\"2\",\"identifier\":\"Base3\",\"JStatus\":\"\"}]}}]";
            string input2 = "[{\"Decision\":{\"id\":\"2\",\"identifier\":\"Base1\",\"dec_id\":12,\"JStatus\":\"\",\"objects\":[{\"id\":\"1\",\"identifier\":\"Base2\",\"JStatus\":\"\",\"textitem\":[{\"id\":\"1\",\"identifier\":\"Base3\",\"JStatus\":\"\",\"objNewActivity\":[{\"id\":\"1\",\"identifier\":\"Base4\",\"JStatus\":\"\"}],\"objNewGebiedsaanwijzingen\":[{\"id\":\"1\",\"identifier\":\"Base5\",\"JStatus\":\"\"}],\"objNewBegrippen\":[{\"id\":\"1\",\"identifier\":\"Base6\",\"JStatus\":\"\"}],\"objNewLocation\":null}]}]}}]";
            
            Root input1Deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(input1);
            Root input2Deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(input2);

            Root resultObject = new Root();

            // Build you comparison logic: 

            int dec_id;
            if (input1Deserialized.Decision.dec_id > input2Deserialized.Decision.dec_id)
            {
                dec_id = input1Deserialized.Decision.dec_id;
            }
            else
            {
                dec_id = input2Deserialized.Decision.dec_id;
            }
            resultObject.Decision.dec_id = dec_id;


            //etc.

            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
        }
    }

    // Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse);
    public class ObjNewActivity
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string identifier { get; set; }
        public string JStatus { get; set; }
    }

    public class ObjNewGebiedsaanwijzingen
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string identifier { get; set; }
        public string JStatus { get; set; }
    }

    public class ObjNewBegrippen
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string identifier { get; set; }
        public string JStatus { get; set; }
    }

    public class Textitem
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string identifier { get; set; }
        public string JStatus { get; set; }
        public List<ObjNewActivity> objNewActivity { get; set; }
        public List<ObjNewGebiedsaanwijzingen> objNewGebiedsaanwijzingen { get; set; }
        public List<ObjNewBegrippen> objNewBegrippen { get; set; }
        public object objNewLocation { get; set; }
    }

    public class Object
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string identifier { get; set; }
        public string JStatus { get; set; }
        public List<Textitem> textitem { get; set; }
    }

    public class Decision
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string identifier { get; set; }
        public int dec_id { get; set; }
        public string JStatus { get; set; }
        public List<Object> objects { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public Decision Decision { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The trick is to create a generic model that can hold the most possible data, then serialize an object set from all your input strings, then do some sort of logic comparison, here I just did a comparison on dec_id, because I have no idea what your model does, and I don't speak dutch.

Also do write unit tests to validate your logic, it helps.

If you need to generate a new model object in C#, simply use this website from your template, to get a new class structure:
https://json2csharp.com/

Comment: okay thanks, my purpose is to compare the objects from previous json versions, if it changes then mark with change status, if new is added then mark as add, and if removed then mark delete in new json. I'll give it try.